# OutofMemory issue in WSO2 ESB 4.6 while using vfs

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We are using a proxy for reading a delimited text file, transforming using smooks, FTL for transformtion and there on to push data using a webservice endpoint.

We are using couple of custom class mediators. For a delimited text file of 25000 records, initially the transactions are fast. As time goes on the transactions slows down and finally stops with an OutOfMemory error.

On analyzing the heap dump, we could find millions of objects retained in heap.

Few data are as follows:

```
org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl 
Objects 821247 
ShallowSize 65699760 
RetainedSize 1729811848

org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMTextImpl 
Objects 11107880 
ShallowSize 799767360 
RetainedSize 802982200
```

We are using `'HttpCoreNIOListener/Sender'` and `'VFSTransportListener/Sender'` as transports.

## Values in nhttp.properties are as follows : (other values are commented)

> http.socket.timeout=120000
>
> http.socket.buffer-size=32768
>
> snd_t_core=20
>
> snd_t_max=100
>
> snd_io_threads=2
>
> lst_t_core=20
>
> lst_t_max=100
>
> lst_io_threads=2

## Values in passthru-http.properties are :

> http.socket.timeout=120000
>
> worker_pool_size_core=400
>
> worker_pool_size_max=500

## Values in synapse.properties are :

> synapse.threads.max = 200
>
> synapse.sal.endpoints.sesssion.timeout.default=600000
>
> statistics.clean.enable=true
>
> synapse.observers=org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker

We even tried splitting the 25000 records into 10 files of 2500 records each and copied one by one in the vfs folder. Still the same behavior.

After each 25000 records we have to restart the esb server. There are around 50 similar proxies deployed. But at a time files are dropped with respect to only one proxy.

From the documentation we could know that wso2 esb can handle millions of transactions but we couldn't pass through few thousands of transactions.

Kindly let us know what may be the problem in our approach and how to solve this memory issue? Files are shared in the link http://sdrv.ms/1ap5uwK

Comment: It seems there is an issue here. Is it possible for you to try the same in latest ESB? Latest version as of now is ESB 4.8.0

Comment: Thanks for your reply isuru. Currently we are using version 4.6. We will test it in version 4.8 and will get back.